# How do I calculate negation(~) of -5

Tags: java, scjp

```
public class UnaryOperator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a= -5;
        System.out.println(~a); // prints 4
    }
}
```

When I do it manually, I get the answer as 6.

Here is how I did it:

```
128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
 0  0  0  0  0 1 0 1
```

As it is a negation I inverted it to the following:

```
         128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
          0  0  0  0  0 1 0 1
    sign -1  1  1  1  1 0 1 0

-----------------------------
             0  0  0  0 1 0 1
add one-->   0  0  0  0 0 1 1  

------------------------------
             0  0  0  0 1 1 0 = 6   
------------------------------
```

I know there's something wrong with what I am doing but I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: `sign -11111010` is not `-5` in two's complement, so you are starting from the wrong number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 is 00000101
-5 is 11111010+00000001 = 11111011
~(-5) is 00000100
so you get 4.

Comment: When 5 is minus sign as -5 don't we invert it from `11111010` to `00000101` ?

Comment: 5 is 00000101. In two's complement, to get the negative of a number, invert all bits and add 1, giving us -5 = 11111011.

Comment: you are right as inverting it from `11111010 to 00000101` and adding one to it doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

You're starting out with -5, which is in two's complement. Thus:

```
    -128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
      1  1  1  1  1 0 1 1 (= -5)
flip: 0  0  0  0  0 1 0 0 (= +4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done much bitwise stuff, but after reading wikipedia for a few seconds it seems like NOT -5 = 4, on wikipedia they used **NOT x = -x - 1**. So the program is correct.

Edit: For unsigned integers, you use **NOT x = y - x** were y is the maximum number that integer can hold.